# Azure Application Gateway: Subnet must only have application gateway

Tags: azure, load-balancing, subnet, azure-application-gateway

I'm facing an error - "Subnet must only have application gateway" while creating an Application Gateway for in my azure network.

I'm following the steps from thid document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-url-route-portal

Tried to look around but could not find any solution.

[image]

Comment: According to the error you have other components using the same subnet. Have you verified that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Tested in my environment working fine for me , You need to create a seperate subnet for application gateway. you cannot use the subnet that is accomplished with other resources. Like wise you can see in below i selected `AzureBastionSubnet` ie already using with `bastion`.***

[image]

***Once i created seperate subnet for AppGtw it is working fine.***

[image]

***Note : If you are using the subnet that is already accomplished with other reources for that subnet you need to Select NSG `None`.***

[image]